# ServiceStack Input string was not in a correct format when enumerable in request

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a very simple Request DTO that is working whenever I populate any property except a `List<int>`. I have also tried an array, I get the same error:

**Error Code:**

```
'((ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.WebServiceException)($exception)).ErrorCode' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
```

**ErrorMessage:**

```
'((ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.WebServiceException)($exception)).ErrorMessage' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
```

**ResponseBody:**

```
 "ResponseStatus":{
 "ErrorCode":"SerializationException",
 "Message":"KeyValueDataContractDeserializer: Error converting to type: Input string was not in a correct format.",
 "StackTrace":"   at ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer.PopulateFromMap(Object instance, IDictionary`2 keyValuePairs) in C:\\src\\ServiceStack\\src\\ServiceStack.Common\\ServiceModel\\Serialization\\StringMapTypeDeserializer.cs:line 108
   at ServiceStack.ServiceHost.RestPath.CreateRequest(String pathInfo, Dictionary`2 queryStringAndFormData, Object fromInstance) in C:\\src\\ServiceStack\\src\\ServiceStack\\ServiceHost\\RestPath.cs:line 331
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.GetRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath) in C:\\src\\ServiceStack\\src\\ServiceStack\\WebHost.Endpoints\\RestHandler.cs:line 106
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName) in C:\\src\\ServiceStack\\src\\ServiceStack\\WebHost.Endpoints\\RestHandler.cs:line 62"
}
```

I'm not sure what to do with this. Its a simple list of ints that causes a crash. If I leave the property empty and use any of the other strings or ints on the DTO, it works just fine. I know ServiceStack is supposed to be able to handle this. I am v 3.9 of ServiceStack.

Here's the (incredibly brief) code:

```
//DTO
Route("/employee")]
public class EmployeeSearch: IReturn<List<Employee>>
{
    public string FirstNameEquals { get; set; }
    public string LastNameEquals { get; set; }

    ...

    public int[] InDepartment { get; set; }
}

...

//Request
//SearchCriteria is of the above type
result.Employees = _client.Get(result.SearchCriteria);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was resolved, along with [this issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/325), by upgrading from 3.9.12 to 3.9.25.